# Some doubts related to the installed demo of Typo3 web site

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.1.x

I have just installed Typo3 (using the **introductionpackage-6.1.1.zip** package) on my local Apache web server on Ubuntu and appear to me the demo website.

The strange thing is that in this demo website I have an horizontal menu (in the header) having the following elements: Get Started, About Typo3, Features, etcetc

But if I click these  links I always obtain the following error message:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /Typo3/about-typo3/ was not found on this server.
```

Except for the **Get Started** link that take me on the homepage

Why? Is it normal? I think that should exist some sample pages related to these links

Someone can help me?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you have mod_rewrite enabled on your apache web server and if the .htaccess is correctly in use